# C++ future.get() return types

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, lambda

--Example Updated--

Here's a bit of code :

```
int retInt(int a) { return a; }
void randomFunction() 
{
    int a = 3;
    auto future = async([&]{ return retInt(a); });
    const auto ret = future.get();
}
```

VS2012 intellisense tells me that 'ret' is a `const < error-type >` and will not let me compile, giving me an output message of:

> [cannot deduce type for 'const auto' from 'void']

If for example I change 'ret' from `const auto` to `const int` and specify an actual type everything compiles just fine, but I'm wondering why the auto version doesn't work and if there would be a possible code change of some sort to make a version with auto compile.

Any ideas?

Note:

Changing the

> auto future = async([&]{ return retInt(a); });

to

> auto future = async([&] ()->int{ return retInt(a); });

yields the same result

Comment: change to `const int ret` doesn't compile on my VS2012: `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'const int'`

Comment: @billz That's strange.. Do you have SP1 installed? It compiles on mine just fine.

Comment: I've Nov CTP installed :), also tested on gcc 4.7.2, failed ...

Comment: @billz Does the code with the actual function instead of the nested lambdas fail as well...?

Comment: it works for me, http://ideone.com/vyT988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra `[]` inside lambda expression, which makes an embedded lambda express. inner lambda returns `1` but outter lamda return type is not specified which is default to void.

change

```
auto afuture = async([&]{ []{ return 1; }; });
```

to:

```
auto afuture = async( []{  return 1; });
const auto ret = afuture.get();
```

Edit:

Your new code just works fine on VS2012 NOV CTP and gcc 4.7.2.

Note:
you are capturing local variable a by reference, it's safe for async thread, you may want to capture it by value.

```
auto future = async([=]{ return retInt(a); });
                    ^^^
```

Sample code compiled:

http://liveworkspace.org/code/X66xE$2

Comment: The nested lambdas were intended; I've merely used them to show a simplified version of a case where a separate function was being called. The outer lambda would capture the variable and the inner lambda the function call. I'll change my example to show this clearer.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why the program succeeded with `const int ret`.

Comment: @billz: Except ... that was the original question.

Comment: @billz Hmm...Does intellisense give you any `const <error-type>` messages when hovering over the `ret` value? After seeing that link I'm guessing this might just be intellisense interfering with the compiler..

Comment: No, it didn't get that warning.

Comment: @dk123 Especially that CTP does *not* provide a functional Intellisense.

Comment: I'd originally hoped that this was something along the lines of a slight error in code on my part, but seeing how the code is getting compiled without error on other compilers, I don't think there's much benefit in keeping this question open. Thank you everyone for the replies!